# Analyze and solve $m \cos^3 x - \sin 2x \sin x-\cos x =0$

Tags: trigonometry

Could you help me with this equation?

$m\cos^3 x-\sin2x \sin x-\cos x=0$

I can solve this one with $m=1$, which is not hard. It seems to me that I need to convert $\sin 2x \sin x$ into some forms of cosine and eventually factorize it, but I can't seem to find a way.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
& m \cos^3 (x) - \sin(2x) \sin (x)- \cos (x) =0 \\
\implies & m \cos^3 (x) - 2\sin(x)\cos(x)\sin(x)-\cos(x)=0 && \text{double angle formula}\\
\implies & m \cos^3 (x) - 2\cos(x)\sin ^2(x)-\cos(x)=0 && \text{grouping the sines}\\
\implies & m \cos^3 (x) - 2\cos(x)\bigl (1-\cos ^2 (x) \bigr)-\cos(x)=0 && \sin^2(x) = 1-\cos^2(x)\\
\implies & (m+2) \cos^3 (x) - 3\cos(x)=0 && \text{group like terms}\\
\implies & \cos^3 (x) - \frac{3}{m+2}\cos(x)=0 && \text{assume $m \neq -2$}\\
\implies & \cos(x) \biggl [\biggl (\cos(x)+\sqrt{\frac{3}{m+2}} \biggr)\biggl (\cos(x)-\sqrt{\frac{3}{m+2}} \biggr) \biggl]=0 && \text{factorizing}\\
\implies & \cos(x) = 0 \quad \cos(x)=\pm\sqrt{\frac{3}{m+2}}
\end{align}

$\cos(x) = 0 \implies x = (2n+1) \pi$ for any $n \in \Bbb Z$

$\cos(x)=\pm\sqrt{\frac{3}{m+2}}$ has real solutions only when $m≥1$.

Comment: That was fast :0

Comment: I was able to come to your second line, but cannot proceed from there. The solution in the back of the book is different though. I think I will post it here.

Comment: I have added comments, if that helps?

Answer (score 0):

$$ m\cos^{3}x-\sin {2x}\sin x-\cos x=0$$

$$ m\cos^{3}x-2\sin^ {2}x \cos x-\cos x=0$$

One solution comes from $ \cos x =0$

$$ m\cos^{2}x-2 (1- \cos^ {2}x) x-1=0$$

$$ \cos ^2 x = \frac {3}{m+2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, for your fast reply, the solution is like this though:
$\implies m\cos^3x-\frac{1}{2}(\cos x-\cos3x)-\cos x=0$

$\implies (m-\frac{1}{2})\cos^3x-\frac{1}{2}\cos x=0$ $[1]$

$\implies (m-\frac{1}{2})(4\cos^3x-3\cos x)-\frac{1}{2}\cos x=0$ 
$\implies \cos x[(4m-2)\cos^2x-3m+1]=0$

$\implies \cos x=0 => x=\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi$ (1)

$\implies (4m-2)\cos^2x-3m+1=0$ (2)

Analyse (2), $m=\frac{1}{2}$ the equation has no roots

$m$ is not $\frac{1}{2}$, then $\cos^2x=\frac{3m-1}{4m-2}$

$\cos x=\pm\sqrt{\frac{3m-1}{4m-2}}$ only when $-1<\frac{3m-1}{4m-2}<1$

Do you think the solution is correct?

Edit: The derivation $sin2xsinx=\frac{1}{2}(cosx-cos3x)$is as followed:
$sin2xsinx = (2sinxcosx)sinx=2sin^2xcosx=(1-cos2x)cosx=(2-2cos^2x)cosx=2cosx-2cos^3x=\frac{1}{2}cosx-\frac{4}{3}cos^3x+\frac{3}{2}cosx=\frac{1}{2}(cosx-cos3x)$

This is quite long, if you ask me.

Comment: How does the first line imply the second line?

Comment: I have numbered the lines in my last edit.

Comment: The step $$2\cos(x)-2\cos^3 (x)=\frac 12 \cos(x) - \frac 43 \cos^3 (x) + \frac 32 \cos (x)$$ is clearly incorrect, since you had $-2\cos^3 (x)$ on the LHS, whereas the RHS has $-\frac 43 \cos^3 (x)$

Comment: You should change sign when multiplying: $\frac{1}{2}(cosx)-\frac{1}{2}(4cos^3x-3cosx)$.

Comment: I honestly don't see anything wrong with your derivation and the solution from the book, which makes it kind of weird. Any further comment?

Comment: Supposing that the solution given by the book is correct, it should hold for ALL values of $m$ and $x$ such that $$\cos (x) = \pm \sqrt{\frac{3m-1}{4m-2}} \qquad -1<\frac{3m-1}{4m-2} <1$$

Comment: So pick, say, $m=0$. Then $\sqrt{\frac{3m-1}{4m-2}}=\frac {1}{\sqrt 2}$, so $x=\frac \pi 4$ is a solution. However, if we plug $m=0$ and $x=\frac \pi 4$ back into the original equation, we get $$(0) - \sin \biggl(\frac \pi 2 \biggl) \sin \biggl( \frac \pi 4 \biggl)- \cos \biggl ( \frac \pi 4 \biggl) = -(1) \biggl(\frac{\sqrt 2}{2} \biggl) - \biggl(\frac{\sqrt 2}{2} \biggl)=-\sqrt 2$$ which is not $0$.

Comment: The condition $-1<\frac{3m-1}{4m-2}<1$ is not applied to $cos^2(x)$. For $cos^2(x)$ to have solutions, we need $0\leqslant \frac{3m-1}{4m-2}\leqslant 1$, meaning $m\leqslant \frac{1}{3}$ and $m\geqslant 1$. So obviously if you pick $m=0$, it is fallen into the interval where the equation does not have any root.

Comment: I think I committed an earlier mistake, I should have specified the condition for $cos^2x$ first. This is not in the book though.

Comment: I still think this problem is weird, how can there be two different solutions which have two different restrictions? Can anyone spot anything wrong with the answer from the textbook?